# Template using in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, templates

i'm using ng-duallist template. I got it here :  https://github.com/tushariscoolster/ng-duallist

I want to use twice in the same html controller. I have created new variable for it but content is always same so how can I separate it?

Comment: no code, no game :)

Comment: ı just add code block

Answer (score 0):

I want to add vm2 to other data content but always same value added two duallist

[hmtl code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIswS.png)

[directives code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vJgc.png)

```
var existingEntries = [];
    var vm = this;
    vm.property = 'controller';

activate();

function activate() {
    vm.leftValue = [];
    vm.rightValue = [];
    vm.addValue = [];
    vm.removeValue = [];

    function loadMoreLeft() {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.reasonOfLack.length; i++) {
            vm.leftValue.push({
                'name': $scope.reasonOfLack[i]
            });

        }
    };

    function loadMoreRight() {
    }


    vm.options = {
        leftContainerScrollEnd: function () {
        },
        rightContainerScrollEnd: function () {
        },
        leftContainerSearch: function (text) {
            console.log(text)
            vm.leftValue = $filter('filter')(leftValue, {
                'name': text
            })

        },
        rightContainerSearch: function (text) {

            vm.rightValue = $filter('filter')(rightValue, {
                'name': text
            })
        },
        leftContainerLabel: 'Uygunsuzluk Sebepleri',
        rightContainerLabel: 'Seçilen Uyunsuzluk Sebepleri',
        onMoveRight: function () {
            console.log('right');
            console.log(vm.addValue);

        },
        onMoveLeft: function () {
            console.log('left');
            console.log(vm.removeValue);
        }

    };
    loadMoreLeft();


    var leftValue = angular.copy(vm.leftValue)

    var rightValue = angular.copy(vm.rightValue)

}
```